# To move blocks of folders within a specific range in bash script

Tags: bash, directory

I have to handle something like 2775 folders, each of which contains some files. Each folder is named as conf+n, where n is a number that ranges from 1 to 2775 (e.g. conf1, ...conf250,...conf2775). I created some parent folders, named A10, A20...A100, A200,...A1000,A2000 etc. The problem is the following: I would like to move the first 100 folders, so conf1-conf100 to A100, conf101-con200 to A200 etc.

The problem is that the total number of folders (2775) is not fixed, since I would like my script to adapt for different ranges of folders.

In my trial script I create 250 conf# folders as well as 25 A# folders, but I got stucked in the process of moving the conf1-conf10 to A10, conf11-conf20 to A20 etc. I tried to create a iterative for loop for that, but it failed.

```
 #!/bin/bash
     for d in ./test_abc/
       do (cd "$d" &&
        for ((i=1;i<=250;i++))
         do
          mkdir $i
         done);
       done
while true; do
   if  [ "250" -le "500" ];
    then
     pfldrs=$((250 / 10))
     echo -en '\n'
     echo -e "\x1B[31m CREATING BLOCKS ...\x1B[0m \x1B[32m $op \x1B[0m"
     echo -en '\n'
      for d in ./test_abc/
       do (cd "$d" &&
        for ((k=1;k<=$pfldrs;k++))
         do
          m=$(($k*10))
           mkdir A$m
         done);
       done
      break
   fi
done
```

I expect the A10 folder to contain folders conf1-con10, folderA20 to contain folders conf11-conf20, etc.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This test `if  [ "250" -le "500" ]` will always be TRUE.

Comment: Yes, in this case yes. But this is a fragment of a much bigger script where I provide several ranges for the creation of folders that depends on the frequency of sampling that the user defines.

Comment: I believe this is a horrible indentation. Doing `echo -en '\n'` is so strange, why not just `echo`? `I create 250 conf# folders` it's just `seq -f './test_abc/%.0f' 1 250 | xargs mkdir`. `so conf1-conf100 to A100` - Do you want to move the `conf2775` into `A2800` or `A2775` ? Just generate numbers from `0` to `( 2775 + 100 ) % 100 * 100` with step `100`, then just move all the files in ranges to the destination.

Comment: `named A10, A20...A100` `so conf1-conf100 to A100` `A10 folder to contain folders conf1-con10, ` - then what for did you create the `A10` and `A20` folders? Are the destination folder names in 100 intervals or in 10 intervals or in 1000 interval?

Comment: The main script has to process ~ 2775 folders. What I posted is a trial one, an example on how it should manage the folders.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple script, But I think there are better ideas.

move.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=$1
target_dir=$2
interval=$3

total_dir=$(basename $(find $source_dir -type d -name "conf*" | sort -Vr | head -1) | sed "s/conf//g")
echo "total $total_dir interval $interval"

target=0
for i in $(seq 1 $total_dir); do
  if [ $i -gt $target ]; then
    target=$(($target + $interval))
    mkdir $target_dir/A$target
  fi

  mv $source_dir/conf$i $target_dir/A$target/ 
done
```

run

```
./move.sh ${source_dir where conf* dirs are exist} ${target_dir where A* dirs will be created} ${interval}

ex) ./move.sh ./conf_dir ./move_dir 10
```

Comment: Cool! I will try your solution immediately! Thanks a lot!